# Elementary Matrices ranking

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

The question asks to label all elementary matrices, which I know are 1 row operation from the identity matrix however I can't understand why my answers are wrong, see image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKlDC.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ive been asked to determine which are elemnetary matrices, and using the definition of an elemneary matrix I believe what I have written are elemenary matrices however the program is saying it is wrong and im curious if i missed something

Answer (score 0):

One of your answers is incorrect. As a hint, I would suggest you think about the shape of the identity matrix, and as a result the shape of an elementary matrix, and see if any of the answers you've selected doesn't match that shape.